# how to loop and append results when json response from API is list of dictionary

Tags: python, list

I calling API in Python which is giving a response (response.json()) as a list or list of dictionary as shown below. But due to pagination I can retrieve only the first 50 results using offset. If I try looping and appending it is failing since I have tried in dictionary from JSON response but not from the list of dictionary.

```
        import requests
        from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
        import json
        import datetime
        from datetime import date    
        url = "https://xxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/users/search?startAt=0"
        auth = HTTPBasicAuth("Email ID", "API Token")
        headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
        response = requests.request("GET", url, auth=auth, headers=headers)
        data = response.json()
        type(data)
```

```
Result: [
{AccountID: 12345,Status:Open}
{AccountID: 456,Status:Open}
{AccountID: 898,Status:Open}
]
```

Please help me to loop through the pages and append the results.

Comment: does the API not return your "next_page" or "next_row" metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping and appending should definitely work here.

```
import requests

url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page='
responses = []
for page_no in range(5):
    resp = requests.get(url + str(page_no))
    responses.append(resp.json())

print(str(responses)[:100])
print(type(responses))
print(type(responses[0]))
```

This prints:

`[{'page': 1, 'per_page': 6, 'total': 12, 'total_pages': 2, 'data': [{'id': 1, 'email': 'george.bluth.....`

`<class 'list'>`

`<class 'dict'>`

Isnt this what youre after? Let me know!